# Cancel movefile operation

Tags: cancellation, reboot, sysinternals, movefile, movefileex

I tried to schedule a movefile (using the sysinternals tool movefile) operation to delete `"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Definition Updates\Backup"` but I forgot the quotes and accidently scheduled `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows` to move to `C:\Users\NAME\Downloads\sysintperms\Defender\Definition`. I feel like I can't restart now. It feels like there is not much documentation on this.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777874/how-to-cancel-deferred-movefileex-operation) article but I don't see that registry key.

Comment: I have no idea about sysinternals but they mentioned that you have to be logged in as admin to be able to delete the keys. Also, is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54258406/8658598) helpful?

Comment: Thank you so much doneforaiur, I think that it worked